# Expansion of data

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table with sales data that can go up to 40 months. However not all records go up to 40 months some have matured to 20months let say. Is there anyway I can create the additional records to go up to 40months? I have a primary key in my table that can use to identify which records don't have 60 months of data..I am using qlikview and loading the data via a load statement thanks

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to

- identify the missing dates (for each client/product/or whatever is your data about)
- generate data for the missing dates
- concatenate the generated data back to the original table

Check out the script below for an example (put some comments inside the script itself)

If you need working qvf with the example, please check out [this repo](https://github.com/countnazgul/SO_66921877)

```
RawData:
Load * Inline [
    ClientId, Date      , Value
    1       , 01/01/2021, 1
    1       , 02/01/2021, 2
    1       , 03/01/2021, 3
    2       , 04/01/2021, 4
    2       , 05/01/2021, 5
    3       , 06/01/2021, 6
    3       , 07/01/2021, 7
    3       , 08/01/2021, 8
];

// Get min and max possible dates from the "transactions" table
Dates:
Load
  Min(Date) as MinDate,
  Max(Date) as MaxDate
Resident
  RawData
;

// set the min and max dates as variables
let vMinDate = num(peek('MinDate'));
let vMaxDate = num(peek('MaxDate'));

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table Dates;

// generate table with all possible values
// between the min and max dates
TempCalendar:
Load
  Date($(vMinDate) + recno () - 1, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as TempDate
Autogenerate
  (num($(vMaxDate)) - num($(vMinDate)) + 1)
;

// join the clientId and the dates
// this will create all possible combinations
// between clientId and dates
CliendDates_Temp:
Load distinct
  ClientId
Resident
  RawData
;

join

Load
  TempDate
Resident
  TempCalendar
;

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table TempCalendar;

// join the transactions data with the table containing all
// client <-> dates link
// flag the client <-> dates records (RawDataSource fiels)
CliendDates_Temp1:
Load
  ClientId,
  TempDate as Date
Resident
  CliendDates_Temp
;

join

Load distinct
  ClientId,
  Date,
  1 as RawDataSource
Resident
  RawData
;

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table CliendDates_Temp;


// load only the records that do not exists in the "transactions" table
// add 0 as Value for them#
// concatenate the result to the transactions table
Concatenate (RawData)
Load
  ClientId,
  Date,
  0 as Value
Resident
  CliendDates_Temp1
Where
  RawDataSource <> 1
;

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table CliendDates_Temp1;


/*
At this point the original/transactions table will containt the 
initial data + all the "gap" dates for each client but with Value = 0

ClientId, Date      , Value
1       , 01/01/2021, 1
1       , 02/01/2021, 2
1       , 03/01/2021, 3
1       , 04/01/2021, 0
1       , 05/01/2021, 0
1       , 06/01/2021, 0
1       , 07/01/2021, 0
1       , 08/01/2021, 0
...
/*
```